# flatmap(GenTraversableOnce) on Options

Tags: scala

This doesn't work:

```
val res = myOption flatMap (value => Seq(value, “blo”))
```

But this yes:

```
val res = myOption.toSeq flatMap (value => Seq(value, “blo”))
```

Don't you think `flatMap` on `Option`s should take a `GenTraversableOnce` just like `Seq` does?
Or this code is bad for the readability and I should use a `match` or a `map`/`getOrElse`?

Edit: We also get the same issue on `for`/`yield`.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option.flatMap` returns an `Option`, which is "like" a sequence, but cannot contain more than one element. If it was allowed to take a function, that returned a `Seq`, and it returned a `Seq` containing more than one element, what would be the return value of `flatMap` (remember, it needs to be an `Option`)?

Why does `flatMap` need to return an option in the first place? Well, *all* `flatMap` implementations return the same type they started with. It makes sense: if I have an `Option` of something, and want to transform the contents somehow, the most common use case is that I want to end up with another `Option`. If `flatMap` returned me a `Seq`, would would I do? `.headOption`? That is not a very good idea, because it would potentially silently discard data. `if(seq.size < 2) seq.headOption else throw ....`? Well, this is a little bit better, but looks ugly, and isn't enforceable at compile time.

Converting an `Option` to a `Seq` when you need it on the other hand, is very easy and entirely safe: just do `.toSeq`.

Comment: "remember it needs to be an Option" Why? And why I can do `Seq().flatMap(Option())` but not the other way around? If it took a GenTraversableOnce it would handle all collections including Options

Comment: @Joan I added my response to your comment to the answer

Comment: Very good answer thanks @Dima. I now get all aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Overall semantic of `flatMap` is to work like [monadic `bind`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) method, that means it tends to have signature like

```
[A]this:T[A].flatMap[B](f: A => T[B]): T[B]
```

Sometimes (`SeqLike`) this signature is generalized to

```
[A]this:T[A].flatMap[B](f: A => F[B]): T[B]
```

where `F[B]` is something easily convertible to `T[B]`

So not only `Option`, but also `concurrent.Future`, `util.Try` and [`BindOps`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.package) - extension syntax for scalaz monads have method `flatMap` that does not accept any traversable, but only the same wrapper type .

I.e. `flatMap` is more a thing from monads world, not from collections